# data lost while copying using strrncpy from smaller to bigger data array

Tags: c, bit-manipulation

It is a bit strange but I seem to lose data while doing an strncpy while copying data from a smaller array to bigger array. I a quite lost as to why this happens. Please help!
Here is the code(which has been cut from a larger code)

```
#include <stdlib.h>     
#include <stdio.h>      
#include <string.h>

#define SIZE_UNSIGNED_LONG_LONG 8
#define DATALEN 2048

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

    printf("size of unsigned long long is %d \n", sizeof(unsigned long long));

    //unsigned long long to unsigned char
    unsigned long long a = 3;
    unsigned char cval[8];
    cval[7] = (a & 0xFF);
    cval[6] = ((a >> 8) & 0xFF);
    cval[5] = ((a >> 16) & 0xFF);
    cval[4] = ((a >> 24) & 0xFF);
    cval[3] = ((a >> 32) & 0xFF);
    cval[2] = ((a >> 40) & 0xFF);
    cval[1] = ((a >> 48) & 0xFF);
    cval[0] = ((a >> 56) & 0xFF);

    unsigned char data[2048];
    strncpy((char *)data,(char *)cval, SIZE_UNSIGNED_LONG_LONG);//destination buffer

    //unsigned char to unsigned long long
    unsigned long long counter = 0;
    counter = counter |(data[7]);
    counter = counter |(data[6]<< 8);
    counter = counter |(data[5]<< 16);
    counter = counter |(data[4]<< 24);
    counter = counter |(data[3]<< 32);
    counter = counter |(data[2]<< 40);
    counter = counter |(data[1]<< 48);
    counter = counter |(data[0]<< 56);
    printf("Trial1: counter is = %llu\n", counter);
    counter = 0;
    counter = counter |(data[0]);
    counter = counter |(data[1]<< 8);
    counter = counter |(data[2]<< 16);
    counter = counter |(data[3]<< 24);
    counter = counter |(data[4]<< 32);
    counter = counter |(data[5]<< 40);
    counter = counter |(data[6]<< 48);
    counter = counter |(data[7]<< 56);
    printf("Trial2: counter is = %llu\n", counter);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using *strncpy()*, you should use *memcpy()*. *strncpy()* pads the remaining bytes with zero if the null ('\0') character is found.

Comment: More precise reason would be, `strncpy` will stop copying if `'\0'` or `0` is found. So it may not copy complete data when used in such cases (binary data copy).

Comment: It is a bit complicated. I cannot use memory copy. That being the case, how do I take care of this problem just with str functions?

Comment: @user900785 "I cannot use memory copy" -- Why not? "how do I take care of this problem just with str functions?" -- You don't ... "str" implies that the function stops at a NUL.

Comment: I'm curious, why can't you use *memcpy()*? If all else fails, you can always iterate and do assignment byte by byte.

Comment: ok, this is dumb but I got some memory errors which didn't happen with strcpy. That, I realize now was due to something else. And finally , yes, with the Memcpy I have the desred result! Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe your problem is not there:

```
counter = counter |(data[3]<< 32);
```

Gives a warning:

```
left shift count >= width of type
```

Comment: maybe `counter = counter | ((unsigned long long)data[3] << 32);`